# Oauth: perform callback without reseting session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I already implemented Oauth in my app with variuos providers: google, facebook, etc.
Now I'm trying to implement oauth for twitter but not for login. Is not possible since twitter doesn't provide email as part of the auth info. However I still want to retrieve some tokens needed to tweet/send_private_messages in behalf of the user using the API.

I go to `/users/auth/twitter`, get redirected to twitter's consent screen, accept, go back to my app, all OK. The token and secret I want to harvest is there, but `current_user` is `nil`, so I can't persist them to the user. Seems the OmniAuth middleware is resetting the session as if I was gonna login, but I won't! I Just want the omniauth hash data!

Thoughts?

```
# Gemfile
# ...
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'

# config/routes.rb
# ...
get "/users/auth/twitter/callback", to: 'twitter_oauth_callback#callback'

class TwitterOauthCallbackController < ApplicationController
  before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true }

  def callback
    current_user.twitter_token = omni_auth.credentials.token
    current_user.twitter_secrent = omni_auth.credentials.secret

    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
  end

  private

  def omni_auth() request.env["omniauth.auth"] end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the answer is, do it all over without omniauth,using joust [`OAuth`](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby/). There's a good article about [how to Oauth1](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/03/29/oauth-explained-and-what-it-is-good-for/).

```
class TwitterTokensController < ApplicationController
  TWITTER_API_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com'
  CALLBACK_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/twitter_tokens/callback'

  def new
    session.delete 'twitter.request_token.token'
    session.delete 'twitter.request_token.secret'
    redirect_to request_token.authorize_url(callback_url: CALLBACK_URL)
  end

  def callback
    current_user.update_attributes(
      twitter_token: access_token.token,
      twitter_secret: access_token.secret
    ) if params[:oauth_verifier].present?

    redirect_to social_integrations_home_path
  end

  private

  def access_token
    @access_token ||= request_token.get_access_token oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier]
  end

  def request_token
    @request_token ||= begin
      if session['twitter.request_token.token'] && session['twitter.request_token.secret']
        OAuth::RequestToken.new(consumer,
          session['twitter.request_token.token'],
          session['twitter.request_token.secret']
        )
      else
        rt = consumer.get_request_token oauth_callback: CALLBACK_URL
        session['twitter.request_token.token'] = rt.token
        session['twitter.request_token.secret'] = rt.secret
        rt
      end
    end
  end

  def consumer
    @consumer ||= OAuth::Consumer.new(
      ENV['TWITTER_ID'], ENV['TWITTER_SECRET'],
      site: TWITTER_API_URL
    )
  end
end
```